# What are my options for full system (or at least home directory) encryption?

Tags: macos, security, encryption

I own a MacBook Pro, which is obviously a Laptop, so I want to protect myself in case it ever gets stolen.

On Windows I can use TrueCrypt to do a full system encryption, but would that also be a choice on Mac OS X?

I think that OS X contains a built-in encryption, but when it was released (10.2? 10.3?) I heard it had some really bad flaws that made it unusable.

Is that still the case? What are my options to encrypt either the full drive or at least my home directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Mac OS Lion supports whole disk encryption with the new [Filevault2](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4790).

Answer (score 6):

Mac OS X comes with [FileVault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault) for encrypting your home directory. There isn't a whole lot of customization for it, but it does its job. There are a few downsides, though:

- FileVault does not play well with Time Machine backups. Time Machine can only back up the FileVault encrypted disk image when the user is logged out.
- As FileVault runs it tends to slowly consume disk space. This space is reclaimed at logout, but it can cause problems if your drive is nearly full.

These downsides are the result of FileVault being implemented as an encrypted disk image that is then mounted at login. However, as long as you make sure you regularly log out of your machine they shouldn't present that much of an issue.

It does appear that TrueCrypt [is available](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=supported-operating-systems) for Mac OS X, but I've never used it and don't know how well it works.

Comment: TrueCrypt works perfect on mac OS X.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA Not for whole Disk Encryption though

Comment: Unfortunately FileVault is nowhere near as secure as whole disk encryption; it's even less secure than simply having a truecrypt volume. This is because FileVault simply employs user permissions to restrict access to its contents, which can be easily overcome if an attacker has physical access to your machine.

Comment: @Mike I don't see how Filevault is different than TrueCrypt - both mount encrypted volumes that the operating system protects with user permissions. When unmounted (in the case of Filevault, when the user is logged out) they're both just encrypted files on the disk. It's not full disk encryption, but it's no worse than Truecrypt

Comment: @Kyle TrueCrypt does not employ user permissions; you need to specify a new password for each encrypted volume you create.

Comment: @Mike Resetting the user's password isn't enough to obtain access to their filevault. Now if you're talking about cracking the password with some sort of brute force attack, my guess is that you'd be about as successful at that as cracking a Truecrypt password

Comment: I stand corrected. I was unaware that once FileVault was turned on for an account, one needs to enter a master password to change that account's password even when using another admin account. (I just verified this on my machine)

Answer (score 4):

[PGP whole-disk encryption](http://www.pgp.com/products/wholediskencryption/index.html) supports OS X (10.5 and 10.6, Intel CPUs only), including the boot disk.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution for full disk encryption on OS X. FileVault has it's uses, but doesn't do the whole disk.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/sys-encryption-supported-os you can't use TrueCrypt to encrypt the OS partition on macs. No idea whether it can encrypt the user directory.

Comment: @WWW I couldn’t find that information, where is it exactly? The page you linked shows that OS X is only supported as 32bits.

Comment: I mislinked because of the frames. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

truecrypt 7.0a works like a champ on os x 10.6.6.  It even works with etoken pro 64k!  You can encrypt any container (basically like a disk image).  However, I don't see any way to get it to encrypt the user directory.

Comment: It doesn't do full file system encryption on OS X sadly, which was the question :( Container encryption works fine, but in 2011 it's also kinda lame.