# Encrypt home directory only

Tags: mac, filesystem, filevault, encryption, hfs

I have a shared computer that is primarily for my use, but occasionally when I'm out of the office others would like to use it.

These others require Administrator access to be able to install software etc. but I'm concerned (just as much out of mistake as anything else) about the security of my personal stuff on the machine.

I'm looking for a means to encrypt my home directory that can only be unlocked by my password.

Obviously FV2 doesn't cut it, as the full drive is decrypted as soon as the other user logs in.

Comment: see also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204959/mac-os-x-10-10-5-how-can-i-encrypt-only-my-home-folder-without-apple-filevault?rq=1, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/what-are-my-options-for-full-system-or-at-least-home-directory-encryption?rq=1, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99646/can-i-use-an-encrypted-disk-image-for-my-home-folder?rq=1

Comment: Encrypting your ~/home might not stop people from deleting it if they are admin.

Comment: Deleting is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to encrypt the whole `home` directory but only a few files/directories you could use something like [Hider](http://macpaw.com/hider). It's paid though.

Comment: Well actually, I **do** want to encrypt my whole home directory.